# Settext with sleeps in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, character, sleep, settext

I would like to set a label's text by writing the data on it char by char.

So far the code is

```
public void texting(String inc) {
    String a = "";
    try {
        for (char c : inc.toCharArray()) {
            a = a + String.valueOf(c);
            labelHeader.setText(a);
            System.out.println(a);
            Thread.sleep(300);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }

}
```

The console shows the text exactly as I expect to behave (char by char) however the label waits the end of the procedure and then show the data after with no delays between the characters.

What could be the reason of it, how can I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `sleep` in the current event thread.  You need to use some kind of task or timer (sorry not much experience in JavaFX), start by having a look at [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are blocking the FX Application Thread with `Thread.sleep()`. This is the thread that manages all the ui updates, including rendering the UI and processing user input. Since you are blocking this thread, you prevent it doing its usual work.

Instead, you need to perform the "wait" operation in a background thread, or manage this with some kind of timer. The easiest way is probably to use the [aminmation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/package-summary.html) to implement the timer.

So you could do:

```
public void texting(String inc) {    
    IntegerProperty textLength = new IntegerProperty();
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300)), e -> {
        textLength.set(textLength.get()+1);
        labelHeader.setText(inc.substring(0, textLength.get()));
    });
    timeline.setCycleCount(inc.length());
    timeline.play();

}
```

A slight variation is to create a timeline that executes once and manipulates the length of the substring you extract:

```
public void texting(String inc) {    
    IntegerProperty textLength = new IntegerProperty();
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300 * inc.length())), 
        new KeyValue(textLength, inc.length()));
    labelHeader.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() ->
        inc.substring(0, textLength.get()), textLength));
    timeline.play();

}
```

If you want to do this with threads, you would have to do something like:

```
public void texting(String inc) {
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= inc.length(); i++) {
                String text = inc.substring(0, i);
                Platform.runLater(() -> labelHeader.setText(text));
                Thread.sleep(300);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    t.setDaemon(true); // thread will not stop application exit
    t.start();
}
```

And there are various other options...